# Distributing to different enterprise accounts AppStore

Tags: ios, enterprise, in-house-distribution

this is rather odd for stack overflow, as its not programming. I didn't know where else to go, apple devforums are.. ahh, anyway,

I have created an app, for a company and myself too, its a reference application and hence not tied to any company servers or even my server, think of it as an educational app.

The app is available on AppStore, however, I wanted to offer it to a company, that is not in the list of countries that have Volume Purchase Program.

I wanted to know what are my options here, I want to assume (although I do not know) that the company does have an enterprise iOS developer's license.

In this case, is there a way, i could In-Theory offer them my application For their In-House distribution?

Are there any examples? Lets say that they contracted a third party developer (with the app in AppStore) to make their In-House app build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the company has a developer Enterprise license, then you can take your source code and build and sign using certificates created from their account.  This version of the app can then be distributed within the company.  Note that if this company does not currently have an Enterprise developer account, they will have to sign up for one (requires a D-U-N-S number) and will need to incur the annual cost of $299.

There are a number of things that you need to deal with.  You will need to deal with ownership of your code, ongoing support and recompiling the app for them annually when the certificate expires, etc. since you are not an employee of this company.

This question will probably get closed for being off-topic, but hopefully gives you something to think about.

Comment: Ur awsome! thats right, What If i license the app to them for a period of one year? and periodically support the app for a period of one year. Its a hassle.. but would is it that big of a deal?

One thing though **All this would be work only if they give me their provisions and certificates** else, me giving my code to them would be stupidity

Comment: If anyone can tell me, After the distribution provision expires after 1 year (of enterprise dev account), can the enterprise renew its certificate and continue to use the app or should the app be built again with the renewed provision?

Comment: For an enterprise app, when the distribution certificate expires, the app will no longer run.  The app needs to be rebuilt with a new valid certificate and an update deployed. Also, an existing certificate can be revoked at any point of time which will also stop the app from running.

Comment: I plan to license my app to an enterprise, but i want the license to last one year, from the date of build. But I heard some guys re-packaging the app with their distribution certificates when ever they want, that would be painful!